# In wso2 ESB how to send an image

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

In wso2 ESB I want to send image file using multipart/form-data but that data has to be stored in ESB. I am using a condition in ESB if that condition has met this data(image in multipart/form-data) has to be sent to the endpoint.

flow is like this,

```
call ESB(with image file)-->store image in ESB--> check condition-->if it meets condition--> send the image file or data that is stored to the endpoint.
```

Please help me how to achieve this because while i was trying multipart/form-data seems to be not working properly in WSO2 ESB as content type skips boundary info in header.

Please help me in achieving this integration pattern, if possible please add an example.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment to your post, so here is an article that may help you to get an example and details to realize your goal.

https://www.yenlo.com/blog/wso2torial-i-like-to-move-it-moving-files-with-wso2-esb-vfs-transport-part-1

It's a 3-part article.  I wish you luck!